# (C++) How to delete base class after deleting child class when inherited?

Tags: c++, sdl

I'm making a game with C++ and SDL.
There is '**Screen**' class.
and there are '**StartScreen**' and '**MultiplaySettingScreen**' classes, which inherit '**Screen**' class.

I found out on the console that when I quit the whole game, These classes are constructed in order but for deconstructing, '**Screen**' object is not deleted(freed), whereas '**StartScreen**' and '**MultiplaySettingScreen**' objects are deleted(freed). I think it's a memory leak.

> Screen constructor()!
>
> StartScreen constructor()!
>
> MultiplaySettingScreen constructor()!
>
> ...
>
> StartScreen constructor()!
>
> MultiplaySettingScreen constructor()!

What's going on? What did I do wrong?

---

here's the code.

'**Screen**'

```
class Screen
{
protected:
    SDL_Renderer *rend = nullptr;
    GameObject *screen = nullptr;
    GameObject *arrow = nullptr;
public:
    Screen();
    Screen(SDL_Renderer *renderer);
    virtual ~Screen(){};
    virtual void handleEvents(const Uint8 *keystate, bool *isSelecting, bool *isSingle, bool *isMulti){};
    virtual void Update(){};
    virtual void Render(){};
};

Screen::Screen()
{}

Screen::Screen(SDL_Renderer *renderer)
{
    std::cout << "Screen constructor()!" << std::endl;

    rend = renderer;
    screen = new GameObject("images/startscreen.png", GAME_WIDTH, GAME_HEIGHT, 0, 0, "img");
    arrow = new GameObject("images/arrow.png", 30, 30, 250, 330, "img");
}
```

---

'**StartScreen**'

```
class StartScreen: public Screen
{
public:
    StartScreen(SDL_Renderer *renderer);
    ~StartScreen();
    virtual void handleEvents(const Uint8 *keystate, bool *isSelecting, bool *isSingle, bool *isMulti);
    virtual void Update();
    virtual void Render();
};

   StartScreen::StartScreen(SDL_Renderer *renderer): Screen(renderer)
    {
        std::cout << "StartScreen constructor()!" << std::endl;

        singlePlayMode = new GameObject("SINGLE PLAY", MODE_WIDTH, MODE_HEIGHT, 300, 320);
        multiPlayMode = new GameObject("MULTI PLAY", MODE_WIDTH, MODE_HEIGHT, 300, 380);
        title = new GameObject("Pikachu Volleyball", 400, MODE_HEIGHT, 200, 50);
        explaination = new GameObject("Press Enter on any mode..", 400, MODE_HEIGHT, 200, 200);
        copyright = new GameObject("(C) Jinko, All rights reserved", 400, 50, 200, 500);
    }

StartScreen::~StartScreen()
{
    std::cout << "StartScreen deconstructor()!" << std::endl;

    delete singlePlayMode;
    delete multiPlayMode;
    delete title;
    delete explaination;
    delete copyright;
    delete arrow;
    delete screen;
}
```

---

'**MultiplaySettingScreen**'

```
class MultiplaySettingScreen: public Screen
{
private:
    std::string connectingIp = "127.0.0.1";
    std::string connectingPort = "80";
public:
    MultiplaySettingScreen();
    ~MultiplaySettingScreen();
    virtual void handleEvents(const Uint8 *keystate, bool *isSelecting, bool *isSingle, bool *isMulti);
    virtual void Update();
    virtual void Render();
};

MultiplaySettingScreen::MultiplaySettingScreen()
{
    std::cout << "MultiplaySettingScreen constructor()!" << std::endl;

    host = new GameObject("Host", 400, 400, 200, 200);
    guest = new GameObject("Guest", 400, 400, 300, 200);
    ipInput = new GameObject("Connecting IP: ", 400, 200, 200, 200);
    portInput = new GameObject("Connecting PORT: ", 400, 50, 200, 500);
    SDL_StartTextInput();

    if (SDLNet_Init() == -1)
        std::cout << "SDLNET init failed" << std::endl;
    IPaddress ip;

}

MultiplaySettingScreen::~MultiplaySettingScreen()
{
    std::cout << "MultiplaySettingScreen deconstructor()!" << std::endl;

    SDLNet_Quit();

    delete host;
    delete guest;
    delete ipInput;
    delete portInput;
}
```

---

Comment: What does the debugger tell you? Please make it a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: There can't *really* be a leak after you exit the application. A leak is a problem while the program is *running* since it will keep consuming more and more memory. But as soon as you exit the application, the operating system reclaims *all* memory it ever allocated (including whatever it may have leaked). A memory leak doesn't mean the OS will not be able to reclaim the memory once the application is dead.

Comment: Your `Screen` destructor does nothing. You therefore have no evidence on the console that it isn't called.

Comment: @TedLyngmo There is no result from the debugger because there is no bug. This was only my guess. Sorry for the dirty question. I will add more clean question next time.

Comment: @JesperJuhl OK. I was wrong about the concept of 'leaking memory'. Thanks for that!

Comment: @user207421 It was my mistake. After adding code to it, I checked it works in order. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This program

```
#include "StartScreen.h"
#include "MultiplaySettingScreen.h"

int main() {
    { StartScreen ss(nullptr); }
    { MultiplaySettingScreen mss; }
}
```

outputs

```
(rendered) Screen constructor()!
StartScreen constructor()!
StartScreen deconstructor()!
Screen destructor()!
(default) Screen constructor()!
MultiplaySettingScreen constructor()!
MultiplaySettingScreen deconstructor()!
Screen destructor()!
```

I believe you lacked trace output from your `Screen` class to show you the whole story.

## Screen.h

```
#ifndef SCREEN_H_INCLUDED
#define SCREEN_H_INCLUDED

#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

#include "stuff.h" // or whatever the SDL header(s) are called

class Screen
{
protected:
    SDL_Renderer *rend = nullptr;
    std::unique_ptr<GameObject> screen;
    std::unique_ptr<GameObject> arrow;
public:
    Screen();
    explicit Screen(SDL_Renderer *renderer);
    virtual ~Screen();
    Screen(Screen const&) = delete;
    Screen& operator=(Screen const&) = delete;

    virtual void handleEvents(const Uint8 *keystate, bool *isSelecting, bool *isSingle, bool *isMulti){}
    virtual void Update(){}
    virtual void Render(){}
};

Screen::Screen(SDL_Renderer *renderer)
: rend(renderer)
, screen(std::make_unique<GameObject>("images/startscreen.png", GAME_WIDTH, GAME_HEIGHT, 0, 0, "img"))
, arrow(std::make_unique<GameObject>("images/arrow.png", 30, 30, 250, 330, "img"))
{
    std::cout << "(rendered) Screen constructor()!\n";
}

Screen::Screen() {
    std::cout << "(default) Screen constructor()!\n";
}

Screen::~Screen() {
    std::cout << "Screen destructor()!\n";
}

#endif  // SCREEN_H_INCLUDED
```

## StartScreen.h

```
#ifndef STARTSCREEN_H
#define STARTSCREEN_H

#include "Screen.h"

class StartScreen : public Screen {
public:
    explicit StartScreen(SDL_Renderer *renderer);
    ~StartScreen() override;

    void handleEvents(const Uint8 *keystate, bool *isSelecting, bool *isSingle, bool *isMulti) override {}
    void Update() override {}
    void Render() override {}

private:
    std::unique_ptr<GameObject> singlePlayMode;
    std::unique_ptr<GameObject> multiPlayMode;
    std::unique_ptr<GameObject> title;
    std::unique_ptr<GameObject> explaination;
    std::unique_ptr<GameObject> copyright;
};

StartScreen::StartScreen(SDL_Renderer *renderer)
        : Screen(renderer),
          singlePlayMode(std::make_unique<GameObject>("SINGLE PLAY", MODE_WIDTH, MODE_HEIGHT, 300, 320)),
          multiPlayMode(std::make_unique<GameObject>("MULTI PLAY", MODE_WIDTH, MODE_HEIGHT, 300, 380)),
          title(std::make_unique<GameObject>("Pikachu Volleyball", 400, MODE_HEIGHT, 200, 50)),
          explaination(std::make_unique<GameObject>("Press Enter on any mode..", 400, MODE_HEIGHT, 200, 200)),
          copyright(std::make_unique<GameObject>("(C) Jinko, All rights reserved", 400, 50, 200, 500)) {
    std::cout << "StartScreen constructor()!\n";
}

StartScreen::~StartScreen() {
    std::cout << "StartScreen deconstructor()!\n";
}

#endif  // STARTSCREEN_H
```

## MultiplaySettingScreen.h

```
#ifndef MULTIPLAYSETTINGSCREEN_H
#define MULTIPLAYSETTINGSCREEN_H

#include "Screen.h"

class MultiplaySettingScreen : public Screen {
private:
    std::string connectingIp = "127.0.0.1";
    std::string connectingPort = "80";
public:
    MultiplaySettingScreen();
    ~MultiplaySettingScreen() override;

    void handleEvents(const Uint8 *keystate, bool *isSelecting, bool *isSingle, bool *isMulti) override {}
    void Update() override {}
    void Render() override {}

    std::unique_ptr<GameObject> host;
    std::unique_ptr<GameObject> guest;
    std::unique_ptr<GameObject> ipInput;
    std::unique_ptr<GameObject> portInput;
};

MultiplaySettingScreen::MultiplaySettingScreen()
        : Screen(), host(std::make_unique<GameObject>("Host", 400, 400, 200, 200)),
          guest(std::make_unique<GameObject>("Guest", 400, 400, 300, 200)),
          ipInput(std::make_unique<GameObject>("Connecting IP: ", 400, 200, 200, 200)),
          portInput(std::make_unique<GameObject>("Connecting PORT: ", 400, 50, 200, 500)) {
    std::cout << "MultiplaySettingScreen constructor()!\n";

    SDL_StartTextInput();

    if (SDLNet_Init() == -1)
        std::cout << "SDLNET init failed\n";
    IPaddress ip;
}

MultiplaySettingScreen::~MultiplaySettingScreen() {
    std::cout << "MultiplaySettingScreen deconstructor()!\n";
    SDLNet_Quit();
}

#endif  // MULTIPLAYSETTINGSCREEN_H
```

Comment: I think there is no need to be called for default 'Screen' constructor semantically because rendered constructor. Why is it called grammatically?

Comment: True, not needed here, but for symmetry reasons, I'll usually have it in since the base class has multiple constructors to choose from. The objects are built on each other and construction is done from the base to the subclasses. Destruction is of course done in the reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

> "*I found out on the console that when I quit the whole game, These classes are constructed in order but for deconstructing, 'Screen' object is not deleted(freed), whereas 'StartScreen' and 'MultiplaySettingScreen' objects are deleted(freed). I think it's a memory leak.*"

An empty(*default*) destructor *always* destroys the class when *out-of-scope* or called *explicitly*... Therefore, as noted before, we don't have information as to *how* you may know that `Screen` was not destroyed...

Also, *this* member:

```
SDL_Renderer *rend = nullptr;
```

*`SDL_Renderer`* is a `struct` part of the *C-library* **SDL** and thus does not possess a *C++* `class`-*destructor*... Hence, your renderer is left dangling at destruction of the `Screen` class...

```
virtual ~Screen(){
    // Explicitly destroy the renderer...
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(rend);
    screen->~GameObject(); // Destroy the screen gameobject...
    arrow->~GameObject(); // Destroy the arrow gameobject...
};
```

Comment: You don't call destructors explicitly, and the issue cited is destroying `Screen` itself, not its fields.

Comment: You don't normally call destructors explicitly, as this may result in them being called twice if delete is called), or leaking the heap memory for them if delete is not called.

You should probably call destructors explicitly if you used placement new.